# What's the real result of $\lim_{x\to \infty} x - x$

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

So In a practice problem, I've found some complicated lim to compute and at the end I got this :
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x - x$$

My answer was that it was equal to $0$ , because in my reasoning $x-x = 0$ , But when I asked a math teacher I knew he told me that it was an indeterminated form because as we knows the limits of $\infty - \infty$ is undefined . While my class teacher told me that it was correct, Both teacher are old and very good and I don't know which one is right, because for me bot explanations seems logical, so please let me know what's the right answer and why ?

Also does this fact apply on those limits :

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x} $$ 
*$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is an undefined limits*

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} ax - x $$

*Where $a$ is a known real number*

First I thought that I was good at computing limits but this case really confuse me now !

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x-x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} 0 = 0$. The problem might be in the other part "*at the end I got this*" which you didn't post.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228726/concepts-about-limit-lim-x-to-inftyx-x-and-lim-x-to-inftyx-lim-x

Comment: How did you get that limit?

Comment: For $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x) }=\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{x}{x }$ you can use l´hospital. $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x) }=\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{1}=1 \ \forall \ \ x\neq 0$

Comment: @dxiv : The first limit was this : $\frac{x²}{\sqrt{x²} + 1} + 2 - (-x + 2)$ where x<0

Comment: @AnisSouames If you mean that $x^2 / \sqrt{x^2+1} \sim x$ then that's true, but that doesn't allow you to simply cancel it out with $-x$ (at least not without further supporting arguments). This is *not* a $x-x$ case, as your professor was right to point.

Comment: @AnisSouames Consider [for example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x%5E2+%2F+sqrt(x%5E2%2Bx)+-+x+for+x+to+infinity) that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x^2 / \sqrt{x^2+x} - x) = -1 / 2$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the first one is $0$. The logic that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x)=\infty-\infty$ presumes the addition property of limits holds in this case, when it doesn't. We can say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f+g)(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)+\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$, provided the two limits exist. In this case, where $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$, the individual limits as $x$ goes to $\infty$ do not exist, so we cannot use the addition property. So instead we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(0)=0$.

Similarly, for $\frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})$, the individual limits must exist, and of course the denominator must be nonzero. So we actually have $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{x}{x})=\lim_{x\to\infty}(1)=1$.

For $\lim_{x\to\infty}(ax-x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x(a-1))=(a-1)\lim_{x\to\infty}x$, we see that the limit exists only when $a=1$, and the limit is $0$ in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You are entirely correct that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x)=0.$$  Since $x-x=0$ for all $x$, as $x$ approaches $\infty$ the values of $x-x$ approach $0$ (they are in fact always exactly $0$).

An "indeterminate form" is just a general form of a limit such that you can't say what the limit is *automatically* based on its form.   So for instance, a limit of the form $$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))$$ where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both going to $\infty$ is "indeterminate", because this alone is not enough information to determine the limit.  In your example, the limit was $0$.  But in the example $$\lim_{x\to\infty}((x+1)-x),$$ the limit would be $1$ instead, since $(x+1)-x=1$ for all $x$.  Or if you had $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (2x-x),$$ the limit would not exist (it diverges to $\infty$), since $2x-x=x$ and $x$ is going to $\infty$.

So in any particular example, a limit of "indeterminate form" does have a definite value (or the limit may not exist).  It's just that you can't tell in advance what the limit will be merely from the fact that it looks like "$\infty-\infty$".

Comment: Thank's for the explanation, does this apply to my case given that the first limit was $\frac{x²}{\sqrt{x²} + 1} + 2 - (-x + 2)$ where $x<0$ ?

Comment: It is true in that case that the limit has a definite value (or possibly does not exist).  But it is not obvious how to compute the limit, and it's definitely not correct to just say the limit is the same as $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x)$ since it is not true that $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2} + 1} + 2 - (-x + 2)=x-x$.  If you want more details about how to compute your limit and why you can't say it's $x-x$, I would suggest asking that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What is denoted by $$\infty-\infty$$ is indeed a so-called *indeterminate form*, which can take different values depending on the particular ways to reach the two infinities. Informally, one could express the indeterminate case in your example as

$$\left.(x-x)\right|_{x=\infty}$$ i.e. the difference evaluated at $x=\infty$, though this is not "allowed" in the reals as $\infty\notin\mathbb R$.

But the expression

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x)$$ is *not* an indeterminate form, it is the real $0$, rigorously obtained from the rules of limit calculation.

---

Similarly,

$$\left.\frac xx\right|_{x=\infty}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$ denotes an indeterminate form, and

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac xx=1$$ is the limit of this particular indeterminate form, which is a well-defined real.

By contrast, $\dfrac x{x^2}$ and $\dfrac{x^2}x$ generate two $\dfrac\infty\infty$ forms but

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{x^2}=0,$$ while  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}x$$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x-x $$ is an indeterminate form but it is zero in this particular case.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac xx $$ is an indeterminate form but it is $1$ in this case.

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(ax-x)=(a-1)\lim_{x\to+\infty}x$$

$=+\infty$ if $\;a>1$ and $\;-\infty$ if $a<1$.

Answer (score 0):

For me: the real question stated would be: What is the difference between the function $f(x)=x$ and a function $g(x)=x$ when $x$ goes to infinity.

As the functions are equal for equal values of $x$, this simplifies to $$ \lim_{x \to \infty}  0 = 0$$

So, as functions are equal, there is no indeterminate form.