# Limits at infinity.

Tags: limits

What are the rules for evaluating limits at infinity.

I don't know if l can apply the limits law for $\infty-\infty$ or $\infty/\infty$ etc.

The value of $\lim x - \lim x$ as $x \to \infty$ is undefined  ( infinity).

The value of $\lim (x-x)= \lim 0$ as $x\to \infty$ is zero.

Can we apply the usual laws of limit here ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ ?

Comment: Well it certainly looks like a duplicate but it's unintentional.

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis It you have found the answer you were looking for that's fine. If you have some other doubts let it know.

Answer (score 1):

The addition theorem states that

$$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)\pm g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\pm \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$

*if these limits exist*.

Hence

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-x)\not\equiv\lim_{x\to\infty}x-\lim_{x\to\infty}x$$

raises no contradiction. (In fact this pseudo-paradox is not related to the *variable* going to infinity, it is due to the *function* going to infinity.)

---

Limits to infinity are not essentially different from finite limits. You can always transform

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}f\left(\frac1{|t|}\right).$$

Comment: @user: I could tell you, but the reference is too large to fit in this margin.

Comment: This may not be directly related to the question but regarding infinity-infinity, can it converge to zero ? Consider A=B to be the sum of natural numbers. Is A-B=0 ?

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis: this is answered in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Given

- $f(x) \to \infty$
- $g(x) \to \infty$
- $h(x) \to L>0$

we can always conclude that

$$f(x)+g(x)\to \infty, \quad f(x)\cdot (\pm g(x))\to \pm\infty$$

$$f(x)\pm h(x)\to \infty, \quad f(x)\cdot (\pm h(x))\to \pm\infty$$

and more in general we can apply similar rules when the expression is not in an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

With reference to your example, you are right

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x -\lim_{x\to \infty} x$$

is undefined but

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (x-x)=\lim_{x\to \infty} 0=0$$

Refer also to the related

- [Concepts about limit: $\lim_{x\to \infty}(x-x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}x-\lim_{x\to \infty}x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228726/505767)

Comment: Even in the case that f(x)= - g(x) ?

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis Yes of course, in this case $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to \infty} 0=0$$ but $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) +\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$$ is undefined.